# Force browser to re-run js file after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am facing a problem while trying to call javascript file.

I have a menu in my html file.

```
HOME       ME       ABOUT
```

In my second page (`ME`), I run a js file :

```
alert("running");         // to test if my browser runs my js file
$("#some_id").blabla;     // to do smoething with elements
```

When I switch from `ME` to `HOME`, and then getting back to `ME` again, my browser does not run my js file once again. That means all my jQuery's "get element by id" `$(#some_id")` are out-to-date.

That is because I switch in my menu with ajax call.

How to force browsers to re-run this js file after an ajax call ? Thanks

`HOME` code :

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script src="js/home.js?v=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>"></script>
<script>alert("page : home");</script>
```

`ME` code :

```
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<script src="js/me.js?v=<?php echo uniqid(); ?>"></script>
<script>alert("page : me");</script>

<body> ... </body>
```

in `ME` file, javascript are loaded just once.

Comment: you could put the code from the file into a handler which gets called after the link is clicked/the data is loaded per ajax

Comment: already in it. please see the post. I updated it.

Comment: @divad if you change your page with AJAX calls, why do you keep separate files for each page? I would suggest you to use one file, and in the javascript detect the current page and do your stuff.

Comment: @Karlen, Yes I fixed it. The idea behind my fix was pretty much like yours